# Gradle failed: unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'exclude()'

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to include into my Android project (Android Studio - latest, Gradle) the classes from the Google Endpoints (Python) that I recently coded. The server side is all tested and working.

I'm not used to Gradle, therefore I'm following the documentation at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android). After changing the build.gradle file under *src* (as instructed by the doc) to:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'

    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc') {
        // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
        exclude('xpp3:xpp3')
        exclude('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient')
        exclude('junit:junit')
        exclude('com.google.android:android')
    }

    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
        // Exclude play services, since we're not using this yet.
        exclude('com.google.android.google-play-services:google-play-services')
    }

    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude('com.google.android:android')
    }

    // This is used by the Google HTTP client library.
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:14.0.+')
}
```

Android Studio returns the following error:

```
Gradle 'Project' project refresh failed:
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'exclude()'!
Possible causes could be:  
- you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
- you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
- or there is a mistake in a build script
Build file '/Project/Android/build.gradle' line: 44
: Gradle settings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't like how you've set up the `exclude` statements for your dependencies. If you follow the example in the guide more closely, it should work.

For example, instead of:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc') {
    // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
    exclude('xpp3:xpp3')
    exclude('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient')
    exclude('junit:junit')
    exclude('com.google.android:android')
}
```

use this:

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc') {
    // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
    exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
}
```

It's fine to use the condensed format in the initial `compile` coordinates.

Comment: Do u have any GUIDE to tell me how to use `exclude(group: '', module: '')` ? Please tell me. I don't know how to use it exactly. I always get the error.

Comment: But the gradle guide specifically does not have the parens for exclude. Neither way is working for me.

Comment: @Almo, did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: Here's how I fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518216/gradle-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-exclude

Comment: What if I want to exclude a file?

compile ('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0'){
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
    }